# OpenGL GLFW Changing mesh faces individual colors

Tags: opengl, glsl, glfw

Currently I am rendering mesh triangles like this:

```
// draw the same polygons again
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
shader.setVec3("objectColor", obj_color);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, static_cast<unsigned int>(indices.size()), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

The problem with this code is that I am setting object color inside shader for the full mesh.

What would be a good way to render one single mesh whose faces have different colors?
For now I only know how to set vertex colors, and pass it the fragment shader.

What are the most common ways to set individual face colors?
I only think about duplicating mesh vertices twice to avoid vertex color interpolation.

[image]

My current shader looks like this:

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;

out vec3 FragPos;
out vec3 Normal;
out vec3 LightPos;

uniform vec3 lightPos; 

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;


void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    FragPos = vec3(view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0));
    Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(view * model))) * aNormal;
    LightPos = vec3(vec4(lightPos, 1.0)); // Transform world-space light position to view-space light position
   // FragPos = vec3(model * vec4(aPos, 1.0));
   //Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * aNormal;  
   // gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(FragPos, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 FragPos;
in vec3 Normal;
in vec3 LightPos;

// extra in variable, since we need the light position in view space we calculate this in the vertex shader

uniform vec3 lightColor;
uniform vec3 objectColor;
uniform float f;
uniform float transparency;

void main()
{


   //flat shading
//   vec3 x_ = dFdx(FragPos);
//   vec3 y_= dFdy(FragPos);
//   vec3 normal_ = cross(x_, y_);
//   vec3 norm_ = normalize(normal_);


    // ambient
    float ambientStrength = 0.75;
    vec3 ambient = ambientStrength * lightColor;    
    
     // diffuse 
    vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(LightPos - FragPos);
    float diff = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0);//change "norm_" to "norm" avoid the performance warning and have unwelded view
    vec3 diffuse = diff * lightColor;
    
    // specular
    float specularStrength = 0.01;
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(-FragPos); // the viewer is always at (0,0,0) in view-space, so viewDir is (0,0,0) - Position => -Position
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, norm);  
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), 32);
    vec3 specular = specularStrength * spec * lightColor; 
    
    vec3 shading = (ambient + diffuse + specular)*objectColor;
    //float f = 0.75;
    float r_interpolated =  shading[0] + f * (objectColor[0] - shading[0]);
    float g_interpolated =  shading[1] + f * (objectColor[1] - shading[1]);
    float b_interpolated =  shading[2] + f * (objectColor[2] - shading[2]);

     
    vec3 result = vec3(r_interpolated,g_interpolated,b_interpolated);

    FragColor = vec4(result, transparency);
}
```

Comment: What about a color attribute? `layout (location = 0) in vec3 aColor;`

Comment: For now color attributes sets everything to one color.
It feels there is a two fold problem: a) flat-shading, b) assigning multiple vertex colors

Comment: No. An attribute does not set everything to 1 color, since an attribute is per vertex. You can specify a different color for each vertex.

Comment: So the only way is to duplicate each vertex twice to avoid linear interpolation per triangle?

Comment: No you can use the `falt` interpolation qualifier. e.g.: 2 tringles 0-1-2 and 1-2-3. the color attribute of vertex 0 defines the color of the first triangle and the color attribute of vertex 1 defines the color of the 2nd triangle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `flat` [Interpolation qualifier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Interpolation_qualifiers):

> The value will not be interpolated. The value given to the fragment shader is the value from the Provoking Vertex for that primitive.

Vertex shader

```c
// [...]

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aColor;
flat out vec3 vColor;

void main()
{
    vColor = aColor;

    // [...]
}
```

Fragment shader

```c
// [...]

flat in vec3 vColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = vec4(vColor, 1.0);
}
```

With this implementation, the entire triangle primitive is rendered with one color. If you find an intelligent system for assigning the color attributes to the vertices, you can render all triangles with different colors. e.g. 2 tringles with the indices 0-1-2 and 1-2-3. The color attribute of vertex 0 defines the color of the first triangle and the color attribute of vertex 1 defines the color of the 2nd triangle.

---

An alternative way would be to create an array of colors for each triangle primitive and store this color array in a [Shader Storage Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object). Use [`gl_VertexID`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Shader) to address the color in the vertex shader.

```c
layout(std430, binding = 0) buffer primitiveColors
{
    vec4 colors[];
};

void main()
{
    vColor = colors[gl_VertexID / 3];

    // [...]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that the flat option even exists.
How you would set multiple different colors for different faces?

Comment: It is really tricky to use flat vertex method. For example 6 valence vertices can be hardly described with some flat shading logic.

Comment: @PetrasVestartasEPFL An alternative way would be to create an array of colors for each triangle primitive and store this color array in a Shader Storage Buffer Object. See the new section in the answer.